# Как в QByteArray помещать и извлекать битовые поля без боли?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть QByteArray, как в него поместить, а потом извлечь битовые поля? 
Без побитовых сдвигов.

Comment: А ответ на прошлый вопрос не получается использовать?

Comment: @MBo не-а, не выходит

Comment: Ну так там и вступите в обсуждение.

Comment: @MBo хорошо, как это сделать?

Comment: memcopy же целиком скопируете структуру с битовыми полями.

Comment: @MBo может memcpy? memcopy найти не могу.

Comment: Да, конечно. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам, но не без помощи сообщества.

Код структуры:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // работает без директив
struct srt_t // размер структуры 160 бит или 20 байт
{
    uint8_t one;
    uint8_t two;
    uint16_t three;
    uint32_t four;
    uint64_t five;
    uint32_t six: 16,
             seven: 16;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Код кодирования структуры в QByteArray:

```
    srt_t ht{ 255, 255, 65535, 4294967295, 9223372036854775807, 65535, 65535 };

    QByteArray arr;
    arr.append( reinterpret_cast<char *>( &ht ), sizeof( ht ) );
```

Код декодирования в структуру:

```
    srt_t *pDev1 = reinterpret_cast<srt_t *>( arr.data() );

    qDebug() << pDev1->one;
    qDebug() << pDev1->two;
    qDebug() << pDev1->three;
    qDebug() << pDev1->four;
    qDebug() << pDev1->five;
    qDebug() << pDev1->six;
    qDebug() << pDev1->seven;
```

Comment: А где тут битовые поля?

Comment: @MBo , эта конструкция работает и для привычных битовых полей.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа вот этого (по-памяти):

```
// Допустим 3 бита, второй параметр устанавливает их начальные значения в 0
QBitArray bits(3, false); 
a[0] = 1; a[1] = 0; a[2] = 1; 

// Буфер в который надо перегнать биты
QByteArray buffer;

// Вспомогательный поток на запись в буфер
QDataStream in(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

// Пишем биты в буфер, при помощи потока
in << bits;
```

Чтение (где-то на другом конце земного шара):

```
// Читаем буфер с данными при помощи потока
QDataStream out(buffer);

//Битовый массив
QBitArray bits;

//Из буфера, при помощи потока читаем в битовый массив
out >> bits;
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант. Вот тут есть чуть лучше вариант: https://wiki.qt.io/Working_with_Raw_Data

Comment: @РоманХудобердин хорошо, когда есть выбор )